# Wildcard for Spaces to count them

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, wildcard, spaces

Is there something like a Wildcard for Spaces in a String, so that the are ignored when compairing to Strings but still counted by the Index Number?

```
public class Palindromtest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test[] = {
        "O Genie der Herr ehre mein Ego",
        "O Genie der Herr ehre dein Memo",
        "otto"
    };
    for (String input : test) {
        String inputLowerCase = input;
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        inputLowerCase = inputLowerCase.toLowerCase();
        inputLowerCase = inputLowerCase.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        char[] outputarray = inputLowerCase.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(outputarray);
        input = input.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        //System.out.println(input);
        char[] inputarray = input.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(istPalindrom(inputarray));
        int ergebnis = output(outputarray);
        System.out.println(ergebnis);
    }
}

public static boolean istPalindrom(char[] input){
    return output(input) == -1;
}

public static int output(char[] outputarray) {
   for(int i = 0; i < outputarray.length/2; i++){
       if(outputarray[i] != outputarray[outputarray.length-i-1]){
           return i; //it is no Palindrom
       }
   }
   return -1; // it is a Palindrom
}
```

}

Comment: replace all spaces in the strings with '' (nothing)

Comment: Can you give an example of a couple of different inputs and what transformation/result you expect?  And maybe show us what code you've tried?

Comment: added it down below